# Numpy Array Reversing Diagonal

Tags: python, numpy

Is there an easy way in numpy to reverse the order of the diagonal of a matrix?
I have a 2x2 matrix like this:

```
[ 213 5
  198 24 ]
```

but I want it to be like this:

```
[ 24  5
  198 213 ]
```

I've played around with `np.diagonal`, but not sure how I can do this efficiently without a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one with `np.einsum` -

```
def flip_diag(a):
    w = np.einsum('ii->i',a)
    w[:] = w[::-1]
    return a
```

Another with `np.fill_diagonal` -

```
np.fill_diagonal(a,np.diag(a)[::-1].copy())
```

Another with flattend indexing -

```
a.flat[::a.shape[1]+1] = a.flat[::-a.shape[1]-1]
```

#### Benchmarking

Solutions as functions :

```
# @Quang Hoang's soln
def range_diagonal(a):
    idx = np.arange(len(a))
    a[idx,idx] = np.diagonal(a)[::-1]
    return a    

def fill_diagonal(a):
    np.fill_diagonal(a,np.diag(a)[::-1].copy())
    return a

def flattened_index(a):
    a.flat[::a.shape[1]+1] = a.flat[::-a.shape[1]-1]
    return a
```

Using [`benchit`](https://github.com/droyed/benchit) package (few benchmarking tools packaged together; disclaimer: I am its author) to benchmark proposed solutions.

```
import benchit

funcs = [range_diagonal, flip_diag, fill_diagonal, flattened_index]
in_ = [np.random.rand(n,n) for n in [2,5,8,20,50,80,200,500,800,2000,5000]]
t = benchit.timings(funcs, in_)
t.plot(logx=True, save='timings.png')
```

[image]

`flip_diag` and `flattened_index` look good and choosing one among them could be based on the input array sizes.

Answer (score 1):

For `2x2` matrix:

```
a[::-1].T[::-1]
```

For a general `n x n`:

```
idx = np.arange(len(a))

a[idx,idx] = np.diagonal(a)[::-1]
```

Comment: The general solution does not work. I suggest using ```a[idx,idx] = np.flip(a[idx,idx])```